# Is there a way to specify the culture when using System.Net.WebClient to read the contents of a page?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to render a page with a specific culture using System.Net.WebClient?

For example:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

CultureInfo myCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
// Do something to specify the culture info

client.DownloadString(someUrl);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that the WebClient class does is to perform an HTTP request and read/parse the response. When sending this request you could set headers such as `Accept-Language` using the [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) property:

```
client.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "es-ES";
```

If you are talking about the encoding, when you use the [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) method it will look for the response headers in order to use the proper encoding and if the server sends wrong response header you might have encoding problems. If this is the case you could use the [DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f(VS.80).aspx) method which will return you the response as a byte array and you could apply the proper encoding when converting this array to string.

Comment: WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-uk,uk;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"); Works for me